(ROS) How do I save the image data (as video) I am getting from a ROS node which is subscribing to an image Topic?
I am already seeing the images and the subscribed data, but I want to save it into storagefiles like mp4 or anything else. Since I am studying mechanical engineering, I am not great at programming. Any tip or advice is greatly appreciated
untill now I was only able to get to the data.

More info is needed. Are you trying to do this in Python or C++? What topic name/type are you seeing data on? As a general rule of thumb when trying to save ROS topic data rosbag is generally the first answer.
